# How to match specific characters in a string only when character is surrounded by space on both sides?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

So another regex question:

say i have this string `<p> < Hello World > </p>`. And I wanted to remove the inner `<>`, but not the p-tags.

How would I go about making a regex that matches < or > **only** when they have a space on both sides?

Thanks alot,
Erwin

Comment: Do you mean surrounded by spaces? Like " > " or " < "?

Comment: Good question, I probably mean surrounded by spaces. Good catch.

Comment: Then, please edit your question and the title. It is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick visit to [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) gives us this answer:

```
string.match(\s[<>]\s)
```

Comment: Your regex can be simplified as: - `\s[<>]\s`

Comment: I'll admin Regex still baffles me, but if I do `string.delete("\s[<>]\s")` it strips all the <> including those from the tags...

Comment: You can use `gsub` for that, i.e.: `string.gsub(\s[<>]\s)`. And lose the `"` marks.

Comment: I got it to work, thx. Also the Rubular reference is really nice.